# Prove that a graph cannot have two distinct spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Prove that a graph cannot have two distinct spanning trees.

I'm confused with this proof. More so that I think I'm confused as what distinct in this context means? Initially I thought it was that these $2$ possible spanning trees cannot share the same edges, but in fact, distinct trees may still share some edges.

Any sort of clarification on this would help me a lot. 
Thanks

Comment: The result is simply false as stated: a graph can have many distinct spanning trees. *Distinct* simply means that no two of them are the same tree. (The result is true if the graph is itself a tree.)

Comment: That is actually not true in general. Think of a simple example: the complete graph on $3$ vertices (a triangle). It has three distinct candidate spanning trees. Oh, and even if we interpret *distinct* as trees that *do not share any edge*, the claim is still not true: think of the complete graph on $4$ vertices.

Comment: In fact, if the graph is connected, but is itself not a tree (equivalently, has a cycle), then it *must* have *at least two* distinct spanning trees (distinct in the sense of having at least one different edge). In other words, a graph has exactly one spanning tree if and only if it is itself a tree.

Comment: Is this true if the proposition is changed to 'up to isomorphism'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's $K_4$ with two completely edge-disjoint spanning trees shown as red edges and green edges:

[image]

Here's $K_6$ with *three* edge-disjoint spanning trees:

[image]